# Can someone draw the integrating region? Planes and parabola intersection, 3d plot

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Find the volume of the solid enclosed by the parabolic cylinder $y=x^2$ and the planes $z = 3 + y$ and $z= 4y$ by subtracting two volumes.

$$\text{Volume} = \int_a^b\int_c^d \text{?}\,dy \, dx - \int_a^b\int_c^d \text{?}\, dy \ dx$$

I have a hard time imagining how those planes extend over the x-axis... they're like both on x axis right? do they superimpose, or ... how it's gonna look like? Does anyone have 3d plotting software? Can you plot the two planes, and the parabolic cylinder on a 3d graph?

I tried to sketch, but [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMPu9.jpg) just looks awful :(

Comment: Have you tried Mathematica, or maybe Maple, Matlab or Python? Those can put out some pretty nice graphs with little effort if you have them.